# Just save colored pages of a document?

Tags: color, printing

How can I just save the colored pages of a document? I want to print the colored pages on another printer...

Comment: Nice question.  How are the pages being colored?  Is it by the `xcolor` package or by including colored graphics?

Comment: Sort of response to your comment below: would it be enough if _all_ pages with included graphics were selected?  Or if you were willing to indicate in the document which graphics were coloured and which not?  (Namely, do you want LaTeX to figure out which graphics are coloured and which not?).

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you want to use LaTeX. Maybe [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/) is a solution for you?

Take this to be `color.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={3,7}]{final.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively there is always [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Comment: using pdftk this might be done by `pdftk final.pdf cat 3 7 output color.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, there is a [short shell script](https://superuser.com/questions/234408/count-bw-color-pages-in-pdf) which returns list of color page numbers (not tried personally).